# Sharepoint 2007 Office Sharepoint Server Search error 1067

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2007, error

I have problem with my SharePoint 2007 Office SharePoint Server Search service.

When I try to start the service, I get error:

> 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.

Thank you for your help,

Matej

Comment: Have you checked in "services.msc" that your search service's log on user and its credentials are correctly configured or not?

Comment: @Dikesh Gandhi credentials are ok, I have checked, thank you